# How to find the proportion of values in 1 column that make up the total of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column showing dollars spent on individual items and a column of total expenditure for each ID. I want to know the proportional cost of each individual item on the total expenditure for each ID. How can I do this using `dplyr`? Thanks

```
structure(list(total.expenditures = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), name = structure(c(13L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 14L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 8L), levels = c("advertising", "atv.tractor", 
"bred.does", "capital.improvements", "DMP.compliance", "equipment.maintenance", 
"hospitality", "land.managment", "other", "payroll", "property.taxes", 
"stocker.bucks", "supplemental.feed.food.plots", "surveys"), class = "factor"), 
    dollars = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    name = structure(1:14, levels = c("advertising", "atv.tractor", 
    "bred.does", "capital.improvements", "DMP.compliance", "equipment.maintenance", 
    "hospitality", "land.managment", "other", "payroll", "property.taxes", 
    "stocker.bucks", "supplemental.feed.food.plots", "surveys"
    ), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(c(3L, 17L), 
        c(4L, 18L), 13L, c(2L, 16L), 8L, c(5L, 19L), 10L, c(6L, 
        20L), 14L, 9L, 11L, 12L, c(1L, 15L), 7L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -14L), .drop = TRUE))
```

[image: example of data]
Prop should have 0 values for all $0 and 0.498 for equipment.maintenance, 0.005 for surveys, and  0.498 for DMP.compliance.

Comment: As it is already grouped, do you want `df1 %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(prop = mean(dollars == 1))`

Comment: Are you looking for `df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(prop_cost = total.expenditures/sum(total.expenditures, na.rm = T))`

Comment: It did not work, but it looks like we're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I used `df <- group_by(id,name) %>% mutate(prop_cost = dollars/sum(total.expenditures))` to accomplish my goal.